# How can I swap out the value of a mutable reference, temporarily taking ownership?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a function that takes ownership of some data, modifies it destructively, and returns it.

```rust
fn transform(s: MyData) -> MyData {
    todo!()
}
```

In some situations, I have a `&mut MyData` reference. I would like to apply `transform` to `&mut MyData`.

```rust
fn transform_mut(data_ref: &mut MyData) {
    *data_ref = transform(*data_ref);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2e756b2287714b11e1757cc8ca9f550)

However, this causes a compiler error.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*data_ref` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:10:27
   |
10 |     *data_ref = transform(*data_ref);
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `*data_ref` has type `MyData`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I considered using `mem::swap` and `mem::replace`, but they require that you already have some valid value to put into the reference before taking another one out.

Is there any way to accomplish this? `MyData` doesn't have a sensible default or dummy value to temporarily stash in the reference. It feels like because I have exclusive access the owner shouldn't care about the transformation, but my intuition might be wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It feels like because I have exclusive access the owner shouldn't care about the transformation, but my intuition might be wrong here.

The problem with this idea is that if this were allowed, and the function `transform` panicked, there is no longer a valid value in `*data_ref`, which is visible if [the unwind is caught](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) or inside of [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) handling for the memory `data_ref` points into.

For example, let's implement this in the obvious fashion, by just copying the data out of the referent and back in:

```rust
use std::ptr;

fn naive_modify_in_place<T>(place: &mut T, f: fn(T) -> T) {
    let mut value = unsafe { ptr::read(place) };
    value = f(value);
    unsafe { ptr::write(place, value) };
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Box::new(1234);
    naive_modify_in_place(&mut x, |x| panic!("oops"));
}
```

If you run this program ([Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f768df57bc42f648eaed29e98e6b0fc5)), it will crash with a “double free” error. This is because unwinding from the panicking function dropped its argument, and then unwinding from `main` dropped `x` — which is the same box, already deallocated.

There are a couple of crates designed specifically to solve this problem:
[`take_mut`](https://docs.rs/take_mut/), and [`replace_with`](https://crates.io/crates/replace_with) intended to improve on it. (I haven't used either, particularly.) Both of these offer two options for dealing with panics:

1. Force an abort (program immediately exits with no ability to handle the panic or clean up anything else).
2. Replace the referent of the reference with a *different* freshly computed value, since the previous one was lost when the panic started.

Of course, if you have no valid alternative value then you can't take option 2. In that case, you *might* want to consider bypassing this situation entirely by *adding* a placeholder: if you can store an `Option<MyData>` and pass an `&mut Option<MyData>`, then your code can use `Option::take` to temporarily remove the value and leave `None` in its place. The `None` will only ever be visible if there was a panic, and if your code isn't catching panics then it will never matter. But it does mean that every access to the data requires retrieving it from the `Option` (e.g. using `.as_ref().unwrap()`).

Answer (score 1):

You could derive (or impl) `Clone` for `MyData`, then pass the clone into your destructive transform.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e3a4d737a700ef6baa35160545f0e514

Cloning removes the problem of the data being behind a reference.